# Error when uploading US block group shape file in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I am unable to upload a US block group shape file in R. File name is "shape_file.shp"

It shows the following error:

```
Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file
In addition: Warning message:
use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read

Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: provide a reproducible example, please!

Comment: Please show the code that caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(rgdal)
your_object<- readOGR('path to file', 'the specific layer')
```

most of the time I used this function `'the specific layer'` is the actual name of the file, minus the `.shp`

I hope this helps